# Using \left( & \right) around amsmath's align delimiter ("&")

Tags: amsmath, align, delimiters

I want to align equations (using the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package) inside matching `\left(` and `\right)` commands. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a \left( b &= c \right)\\
    d \left( e &= f \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

But that code gives this error:

> Extra }, or forgotten \right.

The error disappears when I remove the delimiters. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 19):

You cannot split `\left`...`\right` across alignment tabs. One solution is to use the `\big`-delimiters (which don't require pairwise usage):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a \bigl( b &= c \biggr) \\
  d \Bigl( e &= f \Biggr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The above example is just to illustrate some delimiter sizes you can choose from. See section **4.14.1 Delimiter sizes** of the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for more options:

[image]

Alternatively, one can adjust the alignment manually and avoid using `&` altogether. However, the above option is far easier to manage.

Comment: This. Plus: never use `\left` and `\right` as long as you don't need to be bigger than `Bigg`er

Answer (score 3):

You can also accompany (i) `\left(` with `\right.` or (ii) `\left.` with `\right)`. In other words,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a \left( b \right. &=  \left. c \right)\\
    d \left( e \right. &=  \left. f \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In that way, you will not obtain the error that you posted.

Comment: Hi, welcome. The (potential) drawback of this is that it doesn't work well if `b` and `c` has different heights (try replacing `c` with `\frac{a}{c}`).  You'll get different size parenthesis, unless you e.g. add a `\vphantom{\frac{a}{c}}`  on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an incredible useful workaround from the [mathtools-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf), p.29, that even includes line-breaks:

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brackets()
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\brackets{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}
    }
```

**MWE**

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brackets()
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\brackets{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  x &= \brackets*{a &&+ \int_a^b x \,\mathrm{d}x}\\ % auto size
    &= \brackets*{\text{loooong} &&+ (b^2 - a^2)}\\
    &= \brackets[\bigg]{\text{loooong} &&+ (b^2 - a^2)}\\ % manual size
    &= \brackets[\bigg]{\text{loooong} &&\\&&&+ (b^2 - a^2)}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If you look at the pdf documentation for mathtools, on page 29 the symbol that comes after `\catcode` appears to be an apostrophe. But looking at the `.dtx` source code the symbol is actually a backtick.