# Aligned and \left \right

Tags: equations, align

The following aligned equation gives an error 'Extra }, or forgotten \right.':

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
U&=\mathbb{R}^{M N}\\
V&=\mathbb{R}^{2 M N}\\
W&=\mathbb{R}^{4 M N}\\
\min_{v\in V} \left\{E_p(v)&=\|\nabla v\|_{W,1}+\lambda \|\rho(v)\|_{U,1} \right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Removing the `\left` and `\right` commands avoids the error:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
U&=\mathbb{R}^{M N}\\
V&=\mathbb{R}^{2 M N}\\
W&=\mathbb{R}^{4 M N}\\
\min_{v\in V} \{E_p(v)&=\|\nabla v\|_{W,1}+\lambda \|\rho(v)\|_{U,1} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I don't understand why having the alignment marker inside a `\left` `\right` command is an error. How do I align an equation with the alignment inside a `\left` `\right` command?

Comment: It's just not possible (see [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s align delimiter (“`&`”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764)). You can get around it though, either by using `\big`-like delimiters, or following the guidelines in [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the `\left` before the alignment with `\right.` and open another `\left`:

[image]

But this may be problematic if there are different vertical sizes on either side.  In this case the easier solution is to use the fixed size delimiters such as `\big`, `\Big`, etc.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
U&=\mathbb{R}^{M N}\\
V&=\mathbb{R}^{2 M N}\\
W&=\mathbb{R}^{4 M N}\\
\min_{v\in V} \left\{E_p(v)\right.&=\left.\|\nabla v\|_{W,1}+\lambda \|\rho(v)\|_{U,1} \right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```