# Displaying a set of equations lined up by first equals sign

Tags: align

I am trying to display the content of the following, central, but so that the first equals sign in each lines up. This is with ones of the sugested  ways to do this that I found, but it did not work.

```
%
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
$\frac{6}{7}  &{}= R_1 + \frac{1}{2}$,

\newline
$R_1  &{}=  \frac{6}{7} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{6}{14} = R_2 + \frac{1}{3}$,

\newline
$R_2  &{}=  \frac{6}{14} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{21} = R_3 + \frac{1}{11}$,

\newline
$R_3  &{}=  \frac{2}{21} - \frac{1}{11} = \frac{1}{231}$,

\newline
$\frac{6}{7} =  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{231}$,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\newline
```

Comment: I realise I also made mistakes and the maths itself is incorrect, ignore this please. It's too late for me to be doing mental maths! haha

Comment: For examples on the different equation setups, see [How to write a mathematical formula in 2 lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214329/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\newline`, `$` or blank lines in display math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
\frac{6}{7}  &= R_1 + \frac{1}{2},\\
R_1  &=  \frac{6}{7} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{6}{14} = R_2 + \frac{1}{3},\\
R_2  &=  \frac{6}{14} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{21} = R_3 + \frac{1}{11},\\
R_3  &=  \frac{2}{21} - \frac{1}{11} = \frac{1}{231},\\
\frac{6}{7} &=  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{231},
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```