# Amsmath double line equation alignment centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, align, subequations

I need an equation that consists of three parts (or one equation including 3 equations in total), it should look like this:

[image]

My code for now gives me the following:
[image]

So I would like to have the two bottom equations at the ends of the top one, so the top one centered....

Note please that this set of equations should go under one equation in terms of numbering.

my code so far looks as following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: market model}
\begin{aligned}
R_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i} R_{mt} + \epsilon_{it} \\
E(\epsilon_{it} = 0) \qquad var(\epsilon_{it}) = \sigma_{\epsilon_{it}}^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Adding more space in-between the two bottom ones does not yield the desired result either.

Comment: Look at [How to write a mathematical formula in 2 lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214329/5764) and use the `gathered` (or `split`) environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gathered` and not `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq: market model}
\begin{gathered}
R_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i} R_{mt} + \varepsilon_{it} \\
E(\varepsilon_{it} = 0) \qquad \var(\varepsilon_{t}) = \sigma_{\varepsilon_{it}}^2
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note the definition of `\var` to be a math operator, so in particular “var” will be printed upright.

[image]