# Second align within first align environment with equation numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

[image]

Is it possible to align the for statements here, without dropping the equation numbers? `\hfill` and `&&` mess up the placement of the equation numbers for me.

Edit:

Picture of what I get after I tried what was posted as answer

[image]

Comment: Providing a minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates the issue, starting with `\documentclass`, helps those trying to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (if I understand your request correct):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \sum_{\mathclap{p \,=\, 1}}^{i}  s_{tp} - \sum_{\mathclap{p \,=\, 2}}^{i+5}                                       m_{tp} &\leq 0 \qquad
  &&\text{for } i = 1, \dots, 39,\\
  \sum_{\mathclap{p \,=\, i}}^{48} f_{tp} - \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{p \,=\, i-5\\ \hphantom{p \,=\,} -2+1}}}^{46} m_{tp} &\geq 0
  &&\text{for } i = 8, \dots, 48,
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's somehow not working for me: I tried this (just a simple version of your answer): `& \sum_{p=i}^{48} f_{tp} - \sum_{\mathclap{p=i-1-2+1}}^{46} m_{tp} \geq 0 \qquad &&\text{ for } i=9,\dots, 48,\\
& \sum_{p=i}^{48} f_{tp} - \sum_{\mathclap{p=i-5-2+1}}^{46} m_{tp} \leq 0 &&\text{ for } i=9,\dots, 48,\\`, but the page numbers then moved to a next line. Do you know what could cause that?

Comment: I've added a picture of what I get now in the OP.

Comment: @rbm: Do you have the `fleqn` option somewhere in your document?

Comment: @Werner Yes I do, I have it with the `mathstools` package (so `\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}`). Could that cause the problem?

Comment: @Werner I got rid of the `fleqn` now, but then I get a rather similar, still incorrect output with the number on the next line.

Comment: @werner The awkward thing is, that now I tried it in a new `align` environment, separate of the other equations, it worked. But I prefer it in the same environment.

Comment: @werner I figured out that the `\left(` and `\right`) that were in one of the lines caused the problem. I changed them now, but now the brackets in that line don't look as nice. Very odd. Do you have any clue what I could do to solve that issue?

Comment: @rbm: There is no `\left`...`\right` constructions in your example. Please always post *complete*, [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). You can use `\big`-like construction to replicate your `\left`-`\right` constructions. See [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764), [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764) but also [Is it ever bad to use `\left` and `\right`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5764)

Comment: @Werner I know, but the equations that I showed in the OP are part of a large block of about 20 equations. So I thought it would not make sense to copy all of them (the `\left(` and right were in an other equation). Thanks for the suggestion about `\big`, I'll try that out!

Answer (score 1):

Although a minimal working example (MWE) would really be helpful here, like Steven B. already stated, I think I got you.

Try to use `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. It uses `amsmath` and extends it more, so you can use the `\mathclap` command. The lower sum limits of the second summation is causing the gap you dislike:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \sum_{p=1}^{i}s_{tp} - \sum_{p=2}^{i+5}m_{tp} \leq 0 for i = 1,\cdots,39,\\
  \sum_{p=1}^{48}f_{tp} - \sum_{\mathclap{p=i-5-2+1}}^{46}m_{tp} \geq 0 for i = 8,\cdots,48,
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...where is the alignment around the `for` as requested? It seems like your post was also cut short.

Comment: Thanks, but you did not exactly understand what I meant. My mistake, I should have been more specific in the OP. What I want is the part from for to be aligned somewhat more to the right, all at the same level (like in Sven's answer, but that doesn't work for me yet).

Comment: @Werner: I misunderstood his questions, I thought about a different alignment. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Cheesey No problem, I should have been more specific. Do you have an idea what I could change to get it to work (I commented on Sven's solution)?

Comment: I have read it. Can you please post the full minimal working example - like Sven and I did - so we can see what usepackages, documentclass, options (like fleqn) etc. you are using? Because I just tested your code in the comments and the numbering works fine for me.

Comment: @cheesey, The thing is, I have a whole block of around 20 equations. When I paste the lines I have now in a new `align` block, everything works as it should. Just when it is in the same block, it does not. And I don't think it'd be handy to post the whole block of equations

Comment: Hmm, then maybe the problem lies somewhere else. Have you tried to comment out certain lines to see if they cause the problem?

Comment: @Cheesey I was actually already doing that myself too the moment you wrote that. I found out the problem, and it turns out that the `\left(` and `\right)` that were in one of the lines caused the problem. I changed them now, but now the brackets in that line don't look as nice. Very odd.