# Left and right braces on different lines of align

Tags: align, braces

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A = \max\left{B \\
    & C \right}. 
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

My expressions B and C are so long that they need to be on different lines. But then TeX doesn't accept left and right braces being on different lines. What can I do?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

In case the OP posted some code that isn't an MWE:

Comment: Also see [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Added MWE.

Comment: @Werner It seems `\bigl` does not work with braces.

Comment: Oh okay, I also need backslash in front of brace. It works now with `\bigl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braces go by pairs, you have to close or open a fake one to balance them before change line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
A = \max\left\{B\right. \\
    & \left.C \right\}. 
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\max\left\{B\frac{a}{b}\right. \\
    & \left.C \right\}.`