# big equation in flalign

Tags: amsmath, align, multline

I am trying to use a big equation inside flalign. The biggest chunk is the third line and I couldn't figure out how to something akin to `\shoveright` in this third equation, as I want is ending on the right margin. Does anyone know how I can do that in this code?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\def\del{\, \mathrm{d}}
\def\inv{^{-1}}

\begin{flalign*}
&\del L_j= \beta_j^{-2}\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_j\inv+\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv  +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\inv\left\{\tilde{\Sigma}_j^{-3}\left (\Sigma_{\epsilon j}-\Sigma_j\right )\del \Sigma_j\right. & \\
&\phantom{\del L_j=} +\left[1+2\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\right ]\del \tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv &\\
&  \left. +2\left[\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\left (1+2\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )+\left (1+\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )\right ]\del \Psi_{j}\inv\right\}&\\
&\phantom{\del L_j}= \text{right-hand-side number 1}&\\
&\phantom{\del L_j}= \text{right-hand-side number 2}&\\
&\phantom{\del L_j}= \text{etc.} &
\end{flalign*}

\noindent
This text is just to show the left and right margins. This text is just to show the left and right margins.

\multlinegap=0pt
\begin{multline*}
\del L_j= \beta_j^{-2}\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_j\inv+\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\inv\left\{\tilde{\Sigma}_j^{-3}\left (\Sigma_{\epsilon j}-\Sigma_j\right )\del \Sigma_j\right. \\
+\left[1+2\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\right ]\del \tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv\\
\shoveright{\left. +2\left[\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\left (1+2\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )+\left (1+\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )\right ]\del \Psi_{j}\inv\right\}}\\
\shoveleft{\begin{aligned}
\phantom{\del L_j} &= \text{right-hand-side number 1}\\
\phantom{\del L_j} &= \text{right-hand-side number 2}\\
\phantom{\del L_j}  &= \text{etc.}
\end{aligned}}
\end{multline*}

\noindent
This text is just to show the left and right margins. This text is just to show the left and right margins.


\end{document}
```

In the second attempt, the third equation ends at the right margin. The caveat is that the spacing between on equation and the next in the `aligned` is not as large as the one in the previous code using `align`, so I don't regard it as satisfactory.

Also, for some reason my compiler reports over and underfull boxes, even though I cannot see why.

Comment: You should avoid using `\left`...`\right`, which would allow you to break it across lines at your leisure. See [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764) and/or [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764) on how to break it across lines.

Comment: What Mico is saying is that your example does not compile.  Help us to help you, by posting a *complete* minimum working example (MWE).

Answer (score 2):

Given the structure of the formula and the width of the text block, I don't think you can display the equation in fewer than four lines. This necessitates breaking some of the longer parenthetical terms across two or more lines.

By the way, not only do `\left` and `\right` not work across broken lines, they arguably also choose math fences that are inappropriately large for the formula at hand. I suggest using `\bigl` and `\bigr` for the round parentheses and `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` for the square brackets and curly braces.

Finally, I wouldn't use an `flalign` environment, as `align` seems to be perfectly up to the task.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% remove 'showframe' option from real document
\usepackage[letterpaper,showframe]{geometry} 
\def\del{\, \mathrm{d}}
\def\inv{^{-1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\del L_j
&= \beta_j^{-2}
\bigl ( \tilde{\Sigma}_j\inv+\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv  
    +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\bigr ) \inv \Bigl\{ \tilde{\Sigma}_j^{-3}
\bigl (\Sigma_{\epsilon j}-\Sigma_j\bigr )\del \Sigma_j\\
&\quad +\Bigl[1+2\bigl (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\bigr )
   \Sigma_{\epsilon j} \Bigr]\del \tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv \\
&\quad+2\Bigl[\bigl (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\bigr )
   \Sigma_{\epsilon j}\bigl (1+2\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\bigr )\\
&\qquad+\bigl (1+\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\bigr )\Bigr] \del \Psi_{j}\inv \Bigr\}\\
&= \dots\\
&= \dots\\
&= \dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The thin lines in the screenshot are generated by the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package; drop this option in the production version of your paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here a two ways of solving the problem: one with `\flalign*`, `mathrlap` and `mathllap`, the second with `align*`and a sort of `MoveEqRight` — which is only `MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools` with a negative argument. As I didn't know what `\inv` and `\del` were supposed to do, I decided the former was `^{-1}` and the latter `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry} %
\def\del{\relax}
\def\inv{^{-1} }

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}%
\del L_j & = \beta_j^{-2}
  \mathrlap{\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_j\inv+\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\inv\left\{\tilde{\Sigma}_j^{-3}\left (\Sigma_{\epsilon j}-\Sigma_j\right )\del \Sigma_j\right.} \\[-4pt]
 & & & & \cdot \left[1+2\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\right ]\del \tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv& \\[-4pt]
 & & & & & \mathllap{ \left. {}+ 2\left[\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\left (1+2\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )+\left (1+\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )\right ]\del \Psi_{j}\inv\right\}}
 \\
& = \text{right-hand-side number 1}&\\
& = \text{right-hand-side number 2}&\\
& = \text{etc.} &
\end{flalign*}

\begin{align*}%
\del L_j & = \beta_j^{-2}
 \left (\tilde{\Sigma}_j\inv+\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\inv\\[-3pt]
 \MoveEqLeft[-2.5] \cdot \left\{\tilde{\Sigma}_j^{-3}\left (\Sigma_{\epsilon j}-\Sigma_j\right )\del \Sigma_j\right.
 \cdot \left[1+2\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\right ]\del \tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv \\[-3pt]
 \MoveEqLeft[-3.5] \left. {}+ 2\left[\left (\tilde{\Sigma}_{wj}\inv+\Psi_j\inv +\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^2\Psi_j^{-2}\right )\Sigma_{\epsilon j}\left (1+2\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )+\left (1+\rho^{-2}\sigma_x^{-2}\Psi_j\inv\right )\right ]\del \Psi_{j}\inv\right\}
 \\
& = \text{right-hand-side number 1}\\
& = \text{right-hand-side number 2}\\
& = \text{etc.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]