# Extra }, or forgotten \right

Tags: align

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y &= a \\
=& -2c_1\bar{z}_1^2 + 2\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2 + 2\bar{z}_2 \left ( -\bar{z}_1 -c_2z_2 - \frac{3\epsilon}{2}\bar{z}_2 -\sigma_{2,1}\cos(x_1)\Delta x_1 \notag \right. \\
\left. &- \sigma_{2,2}\Delta x_2 -\sigma_{2,3} \Delta u +c_2 \chi_2 \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right ) - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,1}^2\cos^2(x_1) \Delta x_1^2 - \gamma \sigma_{2,2}^2 \Delta x_2^2   - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,3}^2 \Delta u^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The error I get:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \right.
```

The expected result:

[image]

Comment: The alignment character `&` cannot be inside the pair `\left`, `\right`

Comment: `\left` and `\right` can't be separated by `&` or `\\ `.  you have `\left.` all alone at the beginning of the second line, before the `&`.  (and this question has been asked many times before.  here's just one instance: [Using \left( & \right) around amsmath's align delimiter (“&”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/579))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want your code to be compilable, `\left.` should be moved to the next column. But many additional changes are needed for a proper appearance. Some suggestions are in the second example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y &= a \\
=& -2c_1\bar{z}_1^2 + 2\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2 + 2\bar{z}_2 \left ( 
-\bar{z}_1 -c_2z_2 - \frac{3\epsilon}{2}\bar{z}_2 -\sigma_{2,1}\cos(x_1)\Delta x_1 \notag 
\right. \\
 &\left.- \sigma_{2,2}\Delta x_2 -\sigma_{2,3} \Delta u +c_2 \chi_2 \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right ) - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,1}^2\cos^2(x_1) \Delta x_1^2 - \gamma \sigma_{2,2}^2 \Delta x_2^2   - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,3}^2 \Delta u^2
\end{align}

\begin{align}
y &= a \notag\\
& = -2c_1\bar{z}_1^2 + 2\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2 \notag\\
& {}+ 2\bar{z}_2 \left ( 
-\bar{z}_1 -c_2z_2 - \frac{3\epsilon}{2}\bar{z}_2 -\sigma_{2,1}\cos(x_1)\Delta x_1 - \sigma_{2,2}\Delta x_2 -\sigma_{2,3} \Delta u +c_2 \chi_2 \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right )\notag\\
& - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,1}^2\cos^2(x_1) \Delta x_1^2 - \gamma \sigma_{2,2}^2 \Delta x_2^2   - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,3}^2 \Delta u^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, the error message you get arises because the directives `\left.` and `\right)` are separated by an `&` alignment character. While moving the `\left.` instruction to *after* the `&` character will get rid of the immediate error, the layout of the equation still isn't great. In particular, the automatically sized parentheses produced by `\left` and `\right` are much too large and end up visually dominating the entire group of equations. I think you're better off using `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr`, i.e., *not* using auto-sized parentheses.

Your equation may also benefit from being broken up across three instead of just two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y &= a \notag\\
&= -2c_1\bar{z}_1^2 + 2\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2 + 2\bar{z}_2 \Bigl( -\bar{z}_1 -c_2z_2 - \frac{3\epsilon}{2}\bar{z}_2 -\sigma_{2,1}\cos(x_1)\Delta x_1 \notag \\
&\qquad- \sigma_{2,2}\Delta x_2 -\sigma_{2,3} \Delta u +c_2 \chi_2 \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} \Bigr) - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,1}^2\cos^2(x_1) \Delta x_1^2 \notag\\
&\qquad- \gamma \sigma_{2,2}^2 \Delta x_2^2   - 2\gamma \sigma_{2,3}^2 \Delta u^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```