# alignment of rows in a bmatrix which are themselves bmatrices

Tags: matrices, amsart

in the code below I'd like the elements in each of the rows to be aligned with the corresponding elements in the other rows and the inside brackets in each row to be aligned with the corresponding brackets in other rows yet to adjust size depending on their contents.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a  \begin{bmatrix} b & a_{long} f_{ormula} \end{bmatrix}\\
  c_d  \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{e}{f} & g \end{bmatrix}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
I want $e/f$ aligned with $b$ and $g$ with $a_{long} f_{ormula} $ and the inside brackets to be both aligned with the corresponding brackets in other rows and to adjust to their contents.  What is the easiest way of doing this?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `a & ` and `c_d &` to change to second column?

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but no.  I want `a` to multiply a row vector and `c_d` to multiply a row vector and both of these row vectors to have elements that are aligned and ditto for the brackets surrounding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd set the inner-matrix as a "pseudo-matrix" where you specify the brackets using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\bigl`/`\bigr` constructions. It allows you the break them across the cell boundary but also to maintain a structure-wide columnar alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \left[\begin{array}{c r @{} c c @{} l}
      a   & \bigl[ & bcdefgh &   ijk    & \bigr] \\
    lmnop & \bigl[ &   qr    & stuvwxyz & \bigr]
  \end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Above I've used an outer `array`, but you could also use a `bmatrix`. The spacing between the inner "pseudo-matrix" brackets have been removed using a `@{}` column specification - one advantage of using a pure `array` implementation.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd been hoping for something that resizes the brackets automatically.......  (+1)

Comment: @JPi: Do you have multiple rows in the inner matrices?

Comment: No, I do not, but they can have varying height.

Comment: @JPi: There are more options presented in [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s align delimiter (“`&`”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764). You can also stretch `\left`/`\right` independently from one another by using `\vphantom` constructions. See [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764).