# writing on multiple lines inside begin{align} ... end{align} environment

Tags: align

Consider the result produced by:

```
\begin{align}
a & =  b + c + d \\
  & + e + f + g
\end{align}
```

**I want a similar result** when I put **\left(** and **\right)** such as:

```
\begin{align}
a & =  \left( b + c + d \\
  & + e + f + g \right) 
\end{align}
```

where **\left(** starts on first line and its brother **\right)** is on a different line.

how to achieve that? LaTeX is unable to connect **\left(** and **\right)** when they are on multiple lines.

EDIT: I want this because my actual equation is really long and has \left ( on the first line and \right ) on a different line.

Comment: which document class do you use and which packages do you use? ty :)

Comment: you should post related packages here. not all. :)

Comment: or you can just put a sample image or some clear visualization to understand your question.

Comment: Each cell of `align` and similar display environments is equivalent (for this purpose) to an `\mbox` -- `\left` and the matching `\right` must both be in the same "box", like the opening and closing of a group.  You have them separated by `&`, which is not permitted.  See [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486)

Comment: If the fences will naturally be the same size in different cells, then the "unmatched" one can be matched by a period, as `\left( ... \right. & \left. ... \right)`.  But it's better to use a matching pair of the "big" modifiers, e.g. `\bigl( ... & ... \bigr)`.  This is pretty basic, so I recommend checking out some good basic documentation; see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)