# Automatically sized brackets in an align environment

Tags: equations, align

I want to have larger brackets on the outside and smaller brackets on the inside in something like this:

S(T(z))

which is usually achieved by `S\left(T(z)\right)`

However, I am also in the `align` environment and when I try and type set it as above, an error shows up. Is it not possible? WHat is a workaround?

Comment: Is the example in the beginning/middle of page 29 in https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf what you look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `bigl` and `bigr` construct instead. My guess is that your `left` and `right` were not on the same line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
Q = \bigl(&T(z) + q +\\
    &A(w) \bigr)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: they were on the same line

Comment: @user71207 OK, but does my answer give a solution?

Comment: Yes, it does. Whats the difference between bigl/bigr and left/right, and why does the  former work but latter not?

Comment: @user71207 To be brief, `bigl`and `bigr` do not have to be paired unlike the `left` `right` construct. They are way more flexible, as explained in many posts here.

Comment: @user71207 I meant paired on a single line. There are also a variety of sizes : big, Big, bigg, Bigg.

Comment: @user71207 -- Single line isn't always "good enough".  In environments that are subdivided into cells, i.e., parts are separated by `&`, each cell is effectively an isolated environment, and matching `\left ... \right` are required to be in the same environment.  This is a duplicate of [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486)