# How do i remove this unwanted message displayed in the compiled latex file ("program@epstopdf")?

Tags: align

Here is the relevant code from overleaf:

```
Rearranging van der Waals' equation for pressure:\\
    \begin{align*}
    \left(&P + \frac{n^2a}{V_i^2}\right)(V_i^2-nb) = nRT\\
    &P+\left(\frac{n^2a}{v^2}\right)=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}\\
    &P = \frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{n^2a}{V^2}\\
    \intertext{Substituting this into the formula for work, integrating from the initial to the final volume:}\\
    W = \int P dV &= \int_{V_i}^{V_f} \frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{n^2a}{V^2}\:dV\\
    \end{align*}
```

and here is what is displayed:

[image: compiled version of the latex code]

These are the packages being used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{parskip} 
\newenvironment{calign}
```

The italicised "program@epstopdf" seems to appear out of nowhere and I'd appreciate some help in removing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have `\left`...`\right` span a column - denoted by `&`; you have `\left(&...\right)`. These columns denote different *groups*. The `\left`...`\right` pair can only be in the same group. See [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764)

Comment: Genius! Thank you. Would you like to put your comment into an answer form so I can give the question a tick?

Comment: I vote to close this as a duplicate of: [Using \left( & \right) around amsmath's align delimiter ("&")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160486/using-left-right-around-amsmaths-align-delimiter)

Comment: BTW: Even if Overleaf still displays a PDF after an error message, all errors should always be fixed. The PDFs created this way also very often contain errors that are not necessarily noticeable at first glance. In your case you noticed exactly such an effect of the error. So: Never ignore error messages!

Comment: @cabonah Thanks for the advice. I do tend to ignore errors if I get the desired result in the compiled pdf. Is the "program@epstopdf" message a generic error message? Is there an explanation for why that appeared?