# How do I horizontally align three lines inside a \left( ... \right) construction?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, formatting, mathjax

I want to align three elements inside a `pmatrix` around a character that is inside a `\left( ... \right)` construction. Comments here have told me that the `&` alignment character does not work inside such a construction, which is why I get an error message reading "Misplaced &" when I attempt it.

Here's what I'm typesetting:

```
$$
Q_F = \begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
 (1 + a) × \left(\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2} × &f(u, v) × \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} - \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)\right), \\
 (1 + a) × \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} × &f(u, v) × \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} + \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{6}\right), \\
-(1 + a) × \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} × &f(u, v) × \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} × \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}}{6} - 1\right)
\end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

And here's what I want it to look like, approximated by adding a bunch of `\;` space characters:
[image: Image of aligned expression]

Is there a better way to line up the elements on the "f(u, v)" text instead of throwing in a bunch of extra space characters to force the issue?

Comment: Note that pure mathjax questions are off topic but you can probably formulate that as a latex question

Comment: `align` is a top level display element you can not use it inside anything else perhaps you meant to use `aligned`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The same error message appears in a pure LaTeX environment. I've updated the question to reflect that. I also fixed the align/aligned typo in my code snippet; the problem persists when using `aligned`.

Comment: Did you remember to load `amsmath` in your latex doc?

Comment: It would be better to completely remove the reference to mathjax and just focus on the LaTeX aspect of your question.

Comment: BTW, `\left...\right` aren't allowed to surround a `&`.

Comment: The problem is as @Teepeemm says the `\left ... \right` constructions. They cannot span `&`'s

Comment: And your ` ×` does not map to anything usable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \left( & \right) around amsmath's align delimiter ("&")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160486/using-left-right-around-amsmaths-align-delimiter). Either use fixed size brackets, or placing the `&` outside the first `\left` will give essentially the same result.

Comment: I would move the `&` in front of the `(1+a)` on each line. Then your `\left...\right`'s are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here

- `align` cannot be used inside display math like this (was in an earlier version of the question)
- use `aligned` instead
- you cannot use `\left( ... & ... \right)` that hides the `&` from the macros that looks for it. Move it up before `(1+a)`
- You might get into problems with systems not understanding `×` in the input. I've replaced it with `\times`.

This works just fine in LaTeX (with `amsmath` loaded) and in mathjax with the proper setup:

```
$$
Q_F = \begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
 &(1 + a) \times  \left(\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2} \times f(u, v) \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} - \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)\right), \\
 &(1 + a) \times  \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times f(u, v) \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} + \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{6}\right), \\
-&(1 + a) \times  \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times  f(u, v) \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} \times \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}}{6} - 1\right)
\end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the specific material, you can take as alignment point the `\times` symbol.

However, without `\times` seems better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
Q_F =
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
  (1 + a) &\times \left(\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}
           \times f(u, v)
           \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)}
           - \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)\right),
\\
  (1 + a) &\times \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
           \times f(u, v)
           \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} + \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)
           - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{6}\right),
\\
 -(1 + a) &\times \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
           \times f(u, v)
           \times \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)}
           \times \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)
           - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}}{6} - 1\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
Q_F =
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
  (1 + a) & \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}
            f(u, v)
            \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)}
           - \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)\biggr),
\\[\jot]
  (1 + a) & \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
            f(u, v)
            \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)} + \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)
           - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6}}{6}\biggr),
\\[\jot]
 -(1 + a) & \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
            f(u, v)
            \left(\frac{h(u)}{g(u)}
            \frac{h(u)}{g(u)}\right)
           - \frac{2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}}{6} - 1\biggr)
\end{aligned}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]