# How to make appear right expectation symbol on second line of a splitted equation into align environment

Tags: equations, align, brackets, split

Here below the rendering of Latex code snippet : I can't get to make display the right expectation symbol ( \right> ) on the second line of a splitted equations (on both eq(3) and eq(4))

```
\noindent To calculate the variance we assume ${a_{\ell m, p h}^2}$ is constant in order to not have a random denominator:
\begin{align} 
\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{o}_{\ell}\right) &=\dfrac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^2C_{\ell, p h}^2 f_{\text{sky}}} \left<\left(\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} (|b_{\ell m}|^2 - B_\ell) +  2Re(a_{\ell m}^*b_{\ell m}) \right)^2 \right> \nonumber \\
&=\alpha \sum_{m,m' =-\ell}^{\ell} 
\left<\left(b_{\ell m}b_{\ell m}^* - B_\ell + a_{\ell m}^*b_{\ell m}+a_{\ell m}b_{\ell m}^* \right)\nonumber \\
&\quad\quad\left(b_{\ell m'}b_{\ell m'}^* - B_\ell +  a_{\ell m'}^*b_{\ell m'}+a_{\ell m'}b_{\ell m'}^*\right)\right>
\end{align}
\text{with $=\alpha= \dfrac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^2C_{\ell, p h}^2 f_{\text{sky}}}$}
The terms like $B_\ell \left< a\dots b \dots\right>$ or $\left<bb\dots a\dots b \dots\right>$ where $a_{\ell m}$  appears only once are 0 since a is centered and independent of the rest. After simplification and rearranging of the terms we obtain : 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{o}_{\ell}\right)&=\alpha \sum_{m,m' =-\ell}^{\ell} 
\left<b_{\ell m}b_{\ell m}^*b_{\ell m'}b_{\ell m'}^*\right> - B_\ell^2 +\left<a_{\ell m}^*b_{\ell m}a_{\ell m'}^*b_{\ell m'}\nonumber \\
&+a_{\ell m}b_{\ell m}^*a_{\ell m'}^*b_{\ell m'}+a_{\ell m}^*b_{\ell m}a_{\ell m'}b_{\ell m'}^*+a_{\ell m}b_{\ell m}^*a_{\ell m'}b_{\ell m'}^*\right> \nonumber \\
\end{align}
```

Here the capture of rendering :

[image: issue with right expectation not appearing on both eq(3) and eq(4)]

How to make appear these missing `\right>` expectation symbols ?

Comment: Yeah, you can't use `\left`...`\right` across a group (which is what is happening here. You can use `\bigl`...`\bigr` (and friends) as recommended here: [Left/Right across multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764); [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s align delimiter ("`&`")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486/5764) (possible duplicates).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a good reminder of the downsides of overusing `\left` and `\right`. I'd use explicit sizing instructions, especially `\bigl`, `\bigr`, `\biggl` and `\biggr`. Indeed, the code shown below doesn't contain *any* instances of `\left` and `\right`.

Separately, I'd use judiciously-placed `^{}` particles ("empty exponents") to make sure all the subscript terms are placed at a uniform depth. Oh, and please don't use `\dfrac` for inline-math expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % load 'amsmath' automatically
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var} % variance operator
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\noindent 
To calculate the variance we assume $a^2_{\ell m, p h}$ 
is constant in order to not have a random denominator:
\begin{align} 
\Var(\hat{o}_{\ell}) 
&=\frac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^2C_{\ell, p h}^2 f^{}_{\mathrm{sky}}} 
  \biggl<\biggl(\,\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} 
    (|b^{}_{\ell m}|^2 - B^{}_{\ell}) 
    +2\Re(a^*_{\ell m}b^{}_{\ell m}) \biggr)^{\!2}\, 
  \biggr> \nonumber \\
&=\alpha \sum_{\mathclap{m,m' =-\ell}}^{\ell} 
\bigl\langle (b^{}_{\ell m}b^*_{\ell m} - B^{}_{\ell} 
    + a^*_{\ell m}  b^{}_{\ell m}
    + a^{}_{\ell m} b^*_{\ell m} ) \nonumber \\
&\qquad\qquad\times(b^{}_{\ell m'}b^*_{\ell m'} - B^{}_{\ell} 
  +a^*_{\ell m'}b^{}_{\ell m'} 
  +a^{}_{\ell m'}b^*_{\ell m'}) \bigr\rangle
\end{align}
with $\alpha= 1/\bigl[(2 \ell+1)^2C_{\ell, p h}^2 f^{}_{\mathrm{sky}}\bigr]$.
The terms like $B^{}_{\ell} \langle a\dots b \dots\rangle$ 
or $\langle bb\dots a\dots b \dots\rangle$ 
in which $a^{}_{\ell m}$ appears only once are $0$ 
since $a$ is centered and independent of the rest. After 
simplification and rearranging of the terms we obtain: 
\begin{align}
\Var(\hat{o}_{\ell})
&=\alpha \sum_{\mathclap{m,m' =-\ell}}^{\ell} 
\langle b^{}_{\ell m}b^*_{\ell m} b^{}_{\ell m'}b^*_{\ell m'}\rangle 
  - B^2_{\ell} +\bigl\langle 
        a^*_{\ell m} b^{}_{\ell m}a^*_{\ell m'} b^{}_{\ell m'} \nonumber \\
&\qquad+a^{}_{\ell m}b^*_{\ell m} a^*_{\ell m'} b^{}_{\ell m'} 
       +a^*_{\ell m} b^{}_{\ell m}a^{}_{\ell m'}b^*_{\ell m'} 
       +a^{}_{\ell m}b^*_{\ell m} a^{}_{\ell m'}b^*_{\ell m'}\bigr\rangle  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help !